# Displaying categories

Tags: php, functions, categories

How can I place categories onto a page using short code from the following function.

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_category_list` works on [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) only and needs a `post_id` as a parameter. As a page does not have category, it won't work by default in a page.

If you want to retrieve all the categories on a page, you should use one of the following:

```
wp_list_categories

get_categories( array( 'echo' => false ) );
```

Comment: Hi @ghoul, I've tried changing the return to both of the following that you provided. the top returned the list at the top of the page - not where I placed the code. where as the other returned the text "array"

Comment: I have edited the answer. Passing echo => false will return the values where you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To display it on a page using a shortcode you can add this to your `functions.php`:

```
function display_category_list( $atts ) {
  return get_the_category_list();
}
add_shortcode( 'display-categories', 'display_category_list' );
```

and then on your page simply write `[display-categories]`.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

I suggest looking into the `wp_list_categories`-function since it can display a more detailed list, but I'm not sure what your goal is, so take it as a tip:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/